# Adjust image to fit row height in bootstrap4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have 3 images which i want to fit in columns  (col-4). 2 of the images have dimension 2048x1362. The third one’s dimension is 1362x2048. I am using img-fluid class to fit the images to the width of the column. The width of all the columns is same but the height of the row is 2048 (because of the dimension of the 3rd image). Could I change the row height to 1362 using bootstrap or would I need to change the dimension of the 3rd image?

Answer (score -1):

You cannot apply that exact heights with Bootstrap. So you need to change your image dimensions. Or if you want to apply an exact height you need to do it using custom CSS:

Apply `style="height: 1362px;"` to the row

*or*

Apply this CSS:

```
#customRow{
  height: 1362px;
}
```

Just remember that this way is **not** responsive, and therefore not recommended for most of the use cases.

Comment: sorry, didnt' work. I opened another question based on new observation. Please take a look - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47427614/row-height-is-different-from-height-of-the-element-in-the-row