# row height is different from height of the element in the row

Tags: bootstrap-4

In Bootstrap, I thought that height of a row would be equal to height of the tallest element in one of the columns of the row. I added 4 images, 3 of them had dimension 2048x1362 while 4th image's dimension is 1362x2048. The height of the row I thought was equal to 2048 (see pic).

[image]

To makes the height same across all columns, I added css to explicitly set height of the 4th image.

```
<img src="images/fathersday3.jpg" class="img-fluid  rounded-circle  d-none d-sm-block" style="height:1362px;">
```

But to my surprise, the 4th image got much larger (see pic below)

[image]

Clearly, the height of the row was not 2048 px initially.

My question

1. What was the height of the row when I hadn't added css to `img` tag.
2. How could I make the height same for all the images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you first need to understand how img-fluid works.

Adding an image with dimensions 1362x2048 does not mean that the image will be exactly of that size while displaying within the Bootstrap Grid.

Why? Because you have applied a the class **.img-fluid**. that means your image can only be as wide as the container column. Hence the image width downsizes and the height automatically resizes itself while maintaining the proportions. So, it cannot be said what height your row would have been at that time.

While you can make the height same for the columns (B4 already does that with flexbox). For images, you need to upload them of the same size/proportion for equal heights.

Regarding the thing that surprised you, it happened because you explicitly specified a height to the image. Like I said earlier, the image height downsized because of img-fluid may to some lower value. And when you specified the height, it "had" to make the image height that large. **Hence your image is stretching disproportionately.**